# How to access to the router for advanced configuration?

Tags: networking, router, relay

everyone.

I brought a router which is Huawei WS318 recently and I want to make it as  a  DHCP relay.

But I couldn't find the advanced setting on web page.So I decide to use CLI.

However I couldn't access the router by neither telnet nor ssh.And I found no com port on it.

Then how could I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's very likely that you can't. Consumer-grade routers usually don't provide extra features over CLI, if they have a CLI at all. If you want advanced features, then you usually have to pay premium for it. Check the manual, hopefully it's just buried deep in the UI.

Comment: @gronostaj
I got none about it on online manual,so  I have just to give up?

Emm,is it possible to set up DHCP relay on windows 7,not Server 2008?

Comment: Have you considered installing an open source firmware to the router, like OpenWRT/DD-WRT/Tomato?

Comment: Yeah,but I'm afraid it couldn't be applied to this router.
By the way,which website would you like to go for these router information?
Thanks.